# MpChart show min/max value

Tags: android

I'm using MPChart library to build the charts everything is good, but how can I show min/max values on a chart like:

[image]

Comment: did you find any solution for this. I need solution for this exactly.

Answer (score 0):

> Find out the minimum and maximum value you are getting from json
> before implementing it in graph. Then, at the time of populating value
> in graph, compare the values. if min or max matches, show the value.
> else leave it empty.